Can we configure package-specific build options with a colcon defaults config file?
I wish to configure build options (here: additional cmake definitions) for a single package only.
I know, I can run colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_SOME_CONFIG=1, but this will apply the config option to all packages, which is not what I want. Similarly, when I use the colcon_defaults.yaml file. Actually I am looking for an option to specify these per-package options in a colcon config file (ideally located in the workspace root), e.g.,
{
    "build": {
        "symlink-install": false,
        "cmake-args": ["-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"]
    },
    "my_custom_package": {
        "build": {
            "cmake-args": ["-DCMAKE_SOME_CONFIG=1"]
        }
    }
}

Is something like this already implemented (either by global config, or by adding a custom colcon config file to the package dir)?
Do I need to run several colcon invocations with advanced package selection?
Do I need to edit package code to achieve this?

Found a possible solution here:

If you do not want to go through the “hassle” of installing the mixins and using a command line option for every colcon build call, and, more importantly, want to use different settings for different packages, you can create a .meta file.
colcon build will use the default file colcon.meta, if it exists in the workspace. Otherwise, you can point to another file with the --metas option.
Example: Create the file colcon.meta in your workspace and set package-specific build arguments:
names:
  my_library_package_name:
    cmake-args:
      - "-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
  my_ros_node_package_name:
    cmake-args:
      - "-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug"

Now, when you run colcon build in the workspace, it will build package my_library_package_name in release mode and my_ros_node_package_name and debug mode. This is very useful if you are developing and only need to debug a part of your packages.

